# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'

Tags: python, import

i have a folder format which looks like this:

```
|-checkers with AI
  |-checkers
    |-__init__.py
    |-board.py
    |-constants.py
|-__init__.py
|-main.py
```

the code i am using to import this in board.py is: `from constants import BLACK, ROWS, RED, SQUARE_SIZE`

and for main.py: `from checkers.constants import WIDTH, HEIGHT from checkers.board import Board`

for whatever reason im getting this error, i have spoken to other people and no one seems to have any idea what im doing wrong. i have tried moving all the code into main and running it without importing, doing it that way works but is very messy.

So my code isn't the problem, i have added `__init__.py` into each and have added `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` in main.py
now i am getting the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'` anyone know anything?

Comment: Try importing like from .constants import

Comment: i think its missing a level, move the main.py in first checkers folder

Comment: main.py is already in the "checkers with AI" file and i have changed "from constants" to "from .constants" and that has fixed the issue, i tried that before but for some reason it works now. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't exactly the same as your question, but the top-voted answer is very informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time